# How to add add-on feature to existing .net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a complete website that is in an .aspx file. I have just completed work on a chat window that I would like to just add to the already completed site. I know that with php I could just do something like `include(chatWindow.php);` in the finished php site, but I can't seem to find a way to do with .net. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not enough information here. There are many ways to do this kind of thing in ASP.Net, but we'd need to see more context to know what is appropriate for this app.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn what other information do you need to know?

Comment: What've you got?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the completed site it just html save as an .aspx file. The add-on chat window has it's own html, css, javascript and backend code in c#, all saved in an .aspx file.

Comment: This isn't the place for these kinds of questions. But I think vaguely what you're asking for is relating to .net Master Pages. See https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-master-page-in-asp-net/

Comment: I don't want to have to make any dramatic changes to the original site. If this isn't the place for development questions, where would you suggest I ask them @DubDub? I have already seen that article and I don't think it is the solution I am looking for. I have been researching for the ability to do this for the past 2 days and couldn't find anything that would work.

Comment: @parrigin777 I'm not actually sure where you should ask them, I just know that advice questions don't belong here.

Comment: What is this chat window? Is it a plugin? If so, the plugin's website should give you examples of how to implement it. Did you write it yourself? If you've simply written a new aspx page with the chat window working, why not copy across the code to the site and then run it? It's tough for me to make a suggestion when you've not shown us the website and you've not shown us the plugin.

Comment: Thank you @Stijn, I was actually able to use an answer off of that thread to assist me. Setting up a user control seemed to work, the only issue I'm having now is the .ascx.cs file isn't getting the DLLs.